# Matplotlib subprocess/backend issue

Tags: python, apache, matplotlib, subprocess, backend

I want to plot (i.e. write a file) with matplotlib from a script that runs as a subprocess (launched by a python cgi-script from an apache server), but somehow either the plot isn't created or the server crashes depending on the backend I use. I think I should be using "agg", and the plot is created in that case, but the server crashes then (internal server error). Here's the log:

```
AH01215: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display, referer: http://localhost/
AH01215:   warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning), referer: http://localhost/
AH01215: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py:49: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed, referer: http://localhost/
AH01215:   cursors.MOVE          : gdk.Cursor(gdk.FLEUR),, referer: http://localhost/
malformed header from script 'submit.cgi': Bad header: ['/home/user/..., referer: http://localhost/
```

The cgi-script doens't depend on the output of the subprocess at the moment, so I don't really get the bad-header warning (and there is no such problem when not launching the subprocess). The beginning of the plot-script looks like this:

```
import string
import sys
import os
from math import *
import tempfile
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = tempfile.mkdtemp()
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') 
import matplotlib.pyplot as matplot
from matplotlib import mpl
```

So far I only did rather simple plot with matplotlib and not as subprocesses, so I would really appreciate your help.

PS: I'm using ubuntu 11.04 and apache2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your plot script output stuff to `stdout` and apache is interpreting that as the headers it is expecting from the cgi.

When you call the script with [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), redirect the output to dev null, like this

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT
import os

p = Popen(["ls","-l"], stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: Great - glad to be of service!